# What are the drawbacks of '--allow-file-access-from-files' Google Chrome command line switch?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I find myself frequently needing to have Chrome do XSLT transformations on local XML files. This only works with the aforementioned switch. I am inclined to just add it to my Chrome default shortcut.

Does this switch rule out some functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What are the drawbacks of '--allow-file-access-from-files'?

I can't see any drawbacks to this, apart from possible local security problems if you have infected local files.

You might also want to take a look at [Allow Local File Access in Chrome (Windows)](http://chrisbitting.com/2014/03/04/allow-local-file-access-in-chrome-windows/) where someone has commented that `--allow-file-access-from-files` does **not** allow `xslt transformation`:

> `–allow-file-access-from-files` does not allow anymore `xslt`
>   transformation from local files. How to get that to work in chrome?
>
> xlouk said this on June 12, 2014 at 4:32 am | Reply
>
> I don’t believe this will work with any current Chrome startup
>   options. I would suggest using node and http.server. You can easily
>   create a local http server from a directory. I’ll create a post
>   showing the process.
>
> chrisbitting said this on June 12, 2014 at 8:36 am | Reply

This of course, may be true for older versions of chrome ... but not your version.

---

> --allow-file-access-from-files
>
> By default, `file://` URIs cannot read other `file://` URIs. This is
>   an override for developers who need the old behavior for testing.

Source [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/):

Comment: Thanks for the answer. XSLT transformation does not work at my set up without the switch, but does with the switch, so the second comment simply does not hold true for me. It's a simple XML linking an XSL file, nothing fancy. And creating HTTP servers is frankly shooting sparrows with cannon. Always has, always will be (I hear that suggestion twice a year or so)

Comment: Actually and honestly, I take the earlier comment back -- obviously a lot of Web technologies, including the arguably first one -- hypertext (HTML) -- and its derivatives like XML and even XSLT -- are intrinsically and historically linked to HTTP, so I should note that I was a bit cocky and emotional when I said that "creating HTTP servers is shooting sparrows with cannon, always has always will be". That's was a crude remark. In truth, it's just the overhead I was against, but, like I said, HTTP and HTML/XML/XSLT are so close, evidently one breaks without the other working alongside it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding drawbacks,

One alternative to adding it to your application shortcut is to set a bash alias to your `.bash_profile` or equivalent in your terminal launcher so that you can always easily/quickly launch Chrome with file access it when you need it. This rules out the potential security drawback of using it all the time/keeps it a conscious decision to use it.

Example:
`alias cdev='open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-file-access-from-files'` >> `.bash_profile`.

This allows me to simply type `cdev` from terminal to launch chrome with the appropriate flag.

See: [Stack Overflow: "How do I create a Bash Alias"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967843/how-do-i-create-a-bash-alias)